# Why is Logan locked in a well at the start of The Wolverine?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, the-wolverine

The opening scene of *The Wolverine* shows Logan in a POW camp when the bomb is dropped on Nagasaki. Why is he in a Japanese POW camp and more specifically, why is he locked in a well separate from other prisoners?

Answer (score 8):

**Off-screen reasons**
You're right to question that this part was not answered in any way; except that we are to assume he was caught during his time in the war, and placed in the P.O.W camp - off-screen.

These situations are often left ambiguous so that the writers don't have to explain something that seems unlikely when you really think about it:

- How on earth did Logan get caught in the first place?
- How could they stop him?
- What on earth is he doing in Japan durring WWII, when he was clearly also in Normandy?
- Why in a bloody well even?

This is similar to the age old question: [How did Jaqen H'ghar get caught?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17823/how-did-jaqen-hghar-get-caught)

It is much easier to leave these types of things unexplained so that the reader/viewer can connect the dots themselves. Since, answering could bring up even more questions.

**Well that's just deep**<sup>1</sup>
His solitary confinement in the well is very likely due to the fact that he's, *different*.

Logan is a [berserker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character)#Skills_and_personality)<sup>2</sup>; likely he has displayed his aggression and tendency to go "wild" and out of control, so his Japanese captors would have seen him as *different*<sup>3</sup>, needing to be placed in an extra special circumstances, and treated *very* carefully<sup>4</sup>.

---

<sup>1. Pun intended</sup>

<sup>2. Wikipedia, Wolverine, [Skills and Personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolverine_(character)#Skills_and_personality)</sup>

<sup>3. It's not evident whether or not they are aware of "mutants", but it's safe to assume they realise Logan's a special case</sup>

<sup>4. Note how even young Ichirō Yashida is hesitant to let Logan anywhere near him even once the bomb is imminent.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**He was a prisoner of war**; how else do you get into a POW camp, locked in a cell or a well as the case may be.

Likely the well is the camp's version of solitary confinement for high value or high risk prisoners.

Comment: I am looking for some backstory as to specifics. Plus the war montage in x-men origins shows Wolverine storming the beach at Normandy, so he fought in the European theater during WWII. He would not be in the Pacific theater under a military role as US soldiers did not do tours in both.

Comment: Is Origins in the same continuum as The Wolverine?